# How to cleanly remove a badly installed .deb?

Tags: apt, dpkg, uninstall, package-management

Whenever I try to use `dpkg` or `apt-get`, I get the warning:

```
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 12674 package 'jarnal':
 error in Version string 'build901': version number does not start with digit
```

Looking at the `/var/lib/dpkg/available` file, I find the entry

```
Package: jarnal
Priority: optional
Section: non-free
Maintainer: David K. Levine <david@dklevine.com>
Architecture: all
Version: build901
Depends: sun-java5-jre | sun-java6-jre
Recommends: sun-jai, sun-jai-imageio
Size: 11217466
Description: a Java Notetaker and PDF Annotator... <snip>
```

which corresponds to the `/DEBIAN/control` file in [jarnal-build918_all.deb](http://levine.sscnet.ucla.edu/general/software/tc1000/jarnal-down.htm).
I installed this package about a year ago (before upgrading to 11.04), but can not remove it using apt or dpkg or various frontends.

`locate` find files installed in `/usr/lib/jarnal/`, but it looks incomplete - I think it might be a failed uninstall - since I remember playing with it once, so it must have been properly installed at some point.

Anyway, how can I cleanly remove both the files and the data stored by apt/dpkg from my system?

Comment: What does `dpkg -l jarnal` say?

Comment: ``Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold    
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend    
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)    
||/ Name           Version        Description    
+++-==============-==============-    ============================================
un  jarnal         <none>         (no description available)
``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can back up the `available` file and then empty it (leave it there, but empty).

`apt-get` doesn't need the file at all, `dpkg` sometimes uses it for reference, but it's not essential and it will populate it again after some time.

Another option would be to delete the problematic `jarnal` entry from the `available` file manually.

Answer (score 3):

Edit `/var/lib/dpkg/available` and `/var/lib/dpkg/status` to change the `Version:` line of the `jarnal` package to something dpkg likes, such as `0build901`.

If there's no entry in the `status` file, then by definition you don't have the package installed. It's possible that the uninstall failed and that you didn't finish cleaning up properly; check if there are files `/var/lib/dpkg/info/jarnal.*`. If the package is installed, there should be a file `jarnal.list` with the list of files provided with the package. If you're removing a badly formed package manually, you don't need to worry about the other files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`.

Comment: There is no entry in the `status` file nor any `/var/lib/dpkg/info/jarnal.*`, so I guess I'll just edit the `available` file and remove the files in `/usr/lib/jarnal`. That covers all bases?

Comment: @Simon It looks like the package was uninstalled (no entry in `status`, nothing in `info/jarnal.*`), but there are files left behind. It's impossible to tell whether there are other files left behind. If you still have `jarnal-build901.deb` around, run `dpkg-deb -c jarnal-build901.deb` to see the list of files. You can clean up `available` by editing the `Version` line or removing the whole paragraph starting with `Package: jarnal`.

Answer (score 3):

If these are for not-installed packages, simply run `sudo dpkg --clear-avail` (following [this](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=620958))